# Using std::remove_if with lambda predicate to delete multiple elements

Tags: c++, std

What would be the fastest and most efficient way of using std::remove_if with lambda predicate to delete multiple elements at the same time? At the moment I have a point struct with position and unique id. Inside an update loop we fill the points vector and we add points to be deleted at the end of the update loop. At the moment I have to call remove_if inside a loop to remove all the deleted points from the points vector. For example if we add 10 points per frame and after that we loop all the points to check if the point is outside screen bounds, if it is its added to deletedPoints_.

```
struct Point
{
    /// Position.
    Vector3 position_;
    /// Unique id per point
    int id_;
}

/// Current max id
int maxId_;

/// All points
std::vector<Point> points_;
/// Deleted points
std::vector<Point> deletedPoints_;


//Updates with 60fps
void App::Update()
{
    /// Add 10 points per frame
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        Point newPoint;
        /// Add position
        newPoint.position_ = worldPosition;
        /// Add id starts from 1
        maxId_ += 1;
        startPoint.id_ = maxId_;
        /// Add new point in points
        points_.push(newPoint);
    }

    /// If points outside of screen bounds add them to deletedPoints_
    if (points_.size() > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < points_.size(); ++i)
        {
            /// Bounds
            Vector2 min = Vector2(0.00,0.00);
            Vector2 max = Vector2(1.00,1.00);
            /// Check Bounds 
            if(points_[i].x < min.x || points_[i].y < min.y || points_[i].x > max.x || points_[i].y > max.y)
            {   
                deletedPoints_.push(points_[i]);
            }

        }

        /// Loop deleted points
        for (int i = 0; i < deletedPoints_.size(); ++i)
        {
            int id = deletedPoints_[i].id_;
            /// Remove by id
            auto removeIt = std::remove_if(points_.begin(), points_.end(),
                                  [id](const TrailPoint2& point)
                                  { return point.id_ == id; });
            points_.erase(removeIt, points_.end());
        }
    }


 }
```

Comment: Can't you add a member `toBeDeleted` in `Point` ?

Comment: If sorted by ID, `std::set_difference` is an option.

Comment: If I add a member toBeDeleted I need to loop all the points again where deletedPoints could be less.

Comment: What do you mean by "could be less"?

Comment: With the additional member, you do only one pass instead of `#deletedPoints` passes.

Comment: Just updated my question to show that we are deleting random range per frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without changing your structures, the quickest fix is to invert the whole loop and check `deletedPoints` from *inside* the lambda instead.

Then, make `deletedPoints` a `std::set<int>` storing your unique IDs. Then it'll be relatively fast, because `std::set<int>::find` doesn't need to scan the entire container, though your final complexity will still not be quite linear-time.

```
std::vector<Point> points_;
std::set<int> deletedPointIds_;

/// Remove by id
auto removeIt = std::remove_if(points_.begin(), points_.end(),
                      [&](const TrailPoint2& point)
                      { return deletedPointIds_.count(point.id_); });
points_.erase(removeIt, points_.end());
deletedPointIds_.clear();
```

That being said, whether the switch over to `std::set` will be *actually* faster depends on a few things; you lose memory locality and drop cache opportunities due to the way in which `set`'s elements are stored.

An alternative might be to keep the vector (of IDs not points!), pre-sort it, then use `std::binary_search` to get the benefits of a quick search as well as the benefits of sequentially-stored data. However, performing this search may not be suitable for your application, depending on how much data you have and on how often you need to execute this algorithm.

You could also use a `std::unordered_set<int>` instead of a `std::set`; this has the same problems as a `std::set` but the hash-based lookup may be faster than a tree-based lookup. Again, this entirely depends on the size, form and distribution of your data.

Ultimately, the only way to know for sure, is to try a few things at simulated extents and *measure it*.

Comment: `std::unordered_set` would make that O(1), but I'd still compare it against `std::vector` for performance before blindly using the set.

Comment: Sure, measure the heck out of any solution before settling on it. But this is my gut feel. `std::unordered_set` won't make the whole operation constant, though; you've still gotta loop over `points_`. And, frankly, hashing ints is unlikely to be vastly faster than a tree search, particularly for small containers.

Comment: Yeah, it at least makes the overall loop linear instead of linearithmic. But of course computers don't work directly based on time complexities, which was my main reason for testing `vector` (cache-friendly, iterating over a block of memory, etc.)

Comment: Would it be faster if we sort the IDs ?

Comment: @sabotage3d: Yes, absolutely; that's why the suggested change to `std::set` (with which sorting comes "free" (ish))

Comment: @chris: Thumbs up

Comment: @sabotage3d: It's still algorithmically faster with a set as the search function doesn't need to go over the entire container — it "knows" how the data are laid out. But chris is right that whether that makes your program _actually_ faster depends on a bunch of other stuff as well. You may be able to use `std::binary_search` on a sorted `std::vector` to get the best of both worlds.

Comment: @chris: I relented and summed this all up in the answer itself

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer it is a lot faster than executing the algorithm in a loop.